# Retrieve PRIMARY KEY value from SELECT DISTINCT with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, primary-key, multi-table

I have a set of joined tables that I am querying in the following way:

```
$query = $this->mysqli->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT name, website, email
    FROM sfe
    INNER JOIN ef ON sfe.ID_SFE = ef.ID_SFE
    INNER JOIN f  ON   f.ID_F   = ef.ID_F
    INNER JOIN ad ON  ad.ID_SFE = ef.ID_SFE
    WHERE name         LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR 
          website       LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR
          business_name LIKE '%{$sanitized}%' OR
          email         LIKE '%{$sanitized}%'
");
```

where `ID_SFE` is the primary key of table `sfe` and also the foreign key of `ef`.

When I make this query, I then echo the list of results with the following:

```
while ($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
    $query_result = $result->"name";

    echo "$query_result"
}
```

Because now I would like to also find the value of `ID_SFE` inside the same while loop, I tried to add `ID_SFE` in the list of SELECT DISTINCT together with name, website, email, however, I get `ERROR: There was a problem with the query.`

How can I get the value of `ID_SFE` and store it to another variable inside the while loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not simply add ID_SFE to the list of fields to retrieve, because such field exists in the ad and ef tables.

You will be able to add ad.ID_SFE and/or ad.ID_SFE fields -note you need to specify the table name when specifying the field, as the fields needs to be referenced unequivocally.

Comment: Thank you, Nico, that has indeed resolved the problem.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to hear that. Can you please mark this answer as the right one?